# Am I still legally bound by my NDA if the store owner sold the store?

Tags: non-compete

I want to know if I am still legally bound by an NDA contract that I signed with my employer when I first started the job.  The NDA states that I cannot compete with the store for a 1-year uninterrupted period after termination.  I quit this job 6 months ago, however, the store owner/employer just recently sold the store (which is part of a franchise) to another person.  I want to know if I am still bound by this NDA since he is no longer the owner specified in the NDA contract.

Comment: Ask your lawyer.

Comment: I would say someone could talk about the enforceability of "no compete" clauses and provide some refs to get more info.

Comment: NDA is not a Non Compete. it is a disclosure thing. The Non-Compete Clause is, in essence, a different contract.

Comment: Yeah, someone could. When it involves a specific contract for a specific person, that "someone" is **the person's *lawyer***. @Harper-ReinstateMonica Otherwise we have plenty of potential generic duplicates, so keeping this one open is pointless.

Answer (score 2):

Non-compete clauses are usually drafted in the sense of not harming the *company*, and therefore the sale of a company does not extinguish its rights (and obligations) with respect to others.

You would need to assess whether the language in your clause or contract permits a reasonable interpretation that the intent is to avoid harming the *owner* with whom you signed it. However, that seems unlikely.